# SQL Query Help Finding Highest Order Value From Each Day

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex-5.1

I have two tables, `Customer` and `Order`.

In the `Order` table, I have a column called `date_time` that stores the date and time of an order. I also have the `CustomerID`.

I want to get the customers ID for the orders with the highest value from that day.

This is the query to retrieve the order with the highest amount in each day:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(order_amount) AS "Highest Day Amount", 
    to_char(date_time, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS "ORDER DATE"
FROM 
    orders
GROUP BY 
    to_char(date_time, 'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

I need to use `to_char` because the `date_time` column contains both the date and time (for example: 19/05/2021 17:50) and if I don't use the `to_char` because I have more than one order in each day, it will consider the date to be different, because of the time component, and it will list two orders on that day instead of 1 order with the highest total.

And then I want to fetch the customer id from those orders, however I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get the customers ID for the orders with the highest value from that day.

You should not need `to_char()`, but how you truncate to the date depends on the database.  The key idea is that you want to use a window function:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM (SELECT o.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY to_char(date_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD') ORDER BY order_amount DESC) as seqnum
      FROM orders o
     ) o
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

This returns the entire row with the highest order amount.  You can format the result set how you want.

In Oracle, you can do this with aggregation.  I would recommend:

```
select trunc(date_time), max(order_amount),
       max(customer_id) keep (dense_rank first order by order_amount desc) as customer_id
from orders o
group by trunc(date_time);
```

The `keep` syntax is Oracle's (rather verbose) way of implementing a "first" aggregation function.

Comment: You are a genius this is exactly what i've been looking for thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add your customers IDcto the select and the group by

```
SELECT MAX(order_amount) as "Highest Day Amount", to_char(date_time, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS "ORDER DATE", customerID
 FROM orders GROUP BY to_char(date_time, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), customerID
```

If you want more details from customers, you will need to join this table to customers table